# Ошибка при попытке установки bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

Не знаю как правильно сформулировать вопрос.
Хочу установить bower. При попытке выдаёт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `npm cache clean`

Comment: После ввода npm cache clean появляются те же ошибки, что на скрине. И при новой попытке установить bower, вылазят они же.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло полное удаление git и nodejs с компьютера (со всеми папками создаваемыми в моих документах, appdata и других местах) и установка данных программных продуктов заново.